# What's useful/important to put in a contract for a research-oriented industry position (in the US)?

Tags: career-path, industry, early-career, negotiation, contract

I'm (probably) going back from Academia to Industry after a post-doc. Unlike last time, where I signed a company-standard contract which did not have room for much maneuvering, this time it's a small company with no template and will be their first academically-oriented hire.

I'm not asking so much about the employment conditions aspect of the contract, or about expatriation (in fact, I've asked a separate question about that on expats.SX) - but rather about the nature of the position in terms of doing research, publication / release of code, and other related issues.

What issues, or aspects of the relationship, do you believe it is:

1. useful
2. feasible
3. common/not-unheard-of

to put into such a contract? (I'm asking about the disjunction, not the conjunction, of the above)

Note: I'm in applied Computer Science. You can make your answer more specific to this field or more general.

Comment: To clarify, you're writing your own contract?

Comment: @astronat: Me and the guy in charge of recruiting me are writing a draft together. It has to get past their lawyer, but, essentially, yes. Of course if I write that they have to pay me.... [ONE MIIIIILION DOLLARS](https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f7/b3/25/f7b325dd0ffe15a48a5a0d0885195adb--evil-meme-real-men.jpg)... it might not fly.